# Как активировать работу кнопки закрытия видео, которое находится поверх самого видео?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть видео, которое запускается при клике на блок с описанием.

Не получается активировать действие кнопки с `id="stop"` для того, чтобы видео остановилось, спряталось и вернулось в изначальный вид.

Если кнопку вынести за пределы блока, то работает. Как активировать работу кнопки закрытия поверх самого видео и которая расположена в правом верхнем углу блока?

**Код:**

```js
$('#video').click(function() {
  $('#video-inside')[0].play();
  $('#video-inside').show();
  $("#stop").show();
});
$("#stop").click(function() {
  if ($('#video-inside').get(0).play) {
    $("#video-inside").get(0).pause();
    $("#video-inside").hide();
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#video {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#video video,
#stop {
  display: none;
}

#video video,
.embed-responsive {
  z-index: 2;
}

#stop {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#stop:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#video .video-description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 550px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https:////maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https:////maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section id="video">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="video-description">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTjQ1_aoVNrwReLf3gnXnKRyztZIDQf_MFXidBpSlBvwWAKl2vj" width="100" height="57" alt="play video">
      <h4>Big Buck Bunny.</h4>
      <p>The perfect video of Big Buck Bunny.</p>
      <span>00:10</span>
    </div>
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <video class="embed-responsive-item" allowfullscreen width="100%" id="video-inside" controls poster="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
      <button type="button" id="stop">&times;</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в спылтии к родительскому элементу. Так как кнопка вложена в родителя `<section id="video">` то по клику происходит всплытие события и ролик запускается снова.

```js
$('#video').click(function() {
  $('#video-inside')[0].play();
  $('#video-inside').show();
  $("#stop").show();
});
$("#stop").click(function(event) {
  if ($('#video-inside').get(0).play) {
    $("#video-inside")[0].pause();
    $("#video-inside").hide();
    $(this).hide();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

```css
#video {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#video video,
#stop {
  display: none;
}

#video video,
.embed-responsive {
  z-index: 2;
}

#stop {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#stop:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#video .video-description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 550px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https:////maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https:////maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section id="video">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="video-description">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTjQ1_aoVNrwReLf3gnXnKRyztZIDQf_MFXidBpSlBvwWAKl2vj" width="100" height="57" alt="play video">
      <h4>Big Buck Bunny.</h4>
      <p>The perfect video of Big Buck Bunny.</p>
      <span>00:10</span>
    </div>
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <video class="embed-responsive-item" allowfullscreen width="100%" id="video-inside" controls poster="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
      <button type="button" id="stop">&times;</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```